# PHP CodeIgniter AJAX POST Method Not working

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

i have created data entry form inside modal. On submit button click JS function is called in which data is passed to controller via AJAX post but my controller function is not getting called to insert data into databse

This is my modal data entry form

```
    <form id="saveEmpForm" method="post">
<div class="modal fade" id="addEmpModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel" style="text-align: center;font-weight: bold;font-size: 20px;padding-top: 3%;"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Add New Expense</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">                       
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Expense Type</label>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <select name="expense_type" id="expense_type" class="form-control" required="required">
                        <option value="">Choose Expense Type</option>
                        <option value="1">Daily</option>
                        <option value="2">Weekly</option>
                        <option value="3">Monthly</option>
                        <option value="4">Yearly</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Expense Amount</label>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                  <input type="number" name="expense_amount" id="expense_amount" class="form-control" required="required"> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Description</label>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                  <textarea name="expense_description" id="expense_description" class="form-control" rows="5" required></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <center>
        <button style="margin-left: 8%;border: none;" type="submit" id="expense_insert" name="expense_insert" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Add Expense</b></button>

        <button style="background-color: #252525;color: white;border: none;" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="fa fa-window-close" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Close Window</b></button>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

This is my js function

```
$(document).on('submit', '#saveEmpForm', function(event)  
{
    event.preventDefault();

    var expense_type = $('#expense_type').val();
    var expense_amount = $('#expense_amount').val();
    var expense_description = $('#expense_description').val();

    $.ajax({
        url  : "expense/save",
        type : "POST",
        cache : false,
        contentType : false,  
        processData : false,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        context: this,  
        data : {expenseType : expense_type, expenseAmount : expense_amount, expenseDescription : expense_description},
        success: function(data)
        {
            $('#expense_type').val("");
            $('#expense_amount').val("");
            $('#expense_description').val("");
            $('#addEmpModal').modal('hide');
            listExpense();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

---

This is my controller function

```
public function save()
{
    $add_data = array(              
            //'type' => $this->input->post('expenseType'), 
            //'amount' => $this->input->post('expenseAmount'), 
            //'description' => $this->input->post('expenseDescription'),

            'type' => '1', 
            'amount' => '1200', 
            'description' => 'Testing',
        );

    $data = $this->Expensem->saveExpense($add_data);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

---

This is my model function

```
public function saveExpense($add_data)
{
    $result = $this->db->insert('ospos_expense', $add_data);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Post the console output of ajax call.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) expense/save. The console says that controller method cannot be loaded

Comment: @TaimoorAliZafar have you checked the AJAX URL . is it correct?

Comment: POST http://localhost:12345/example.com/public/expense/save 403 (Forbidden). This is error but once i right click and open in new tab url works fine and data gets inserts as i am passing fixed values in controller but actually this url should called via AJAX post which is not happening

Answer (score 0):

@TaimoorAliZafar You can try serializing your form input data like this.

```js
$('#saveEmpForm').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
//console.log($('#saveEmpForm').serialize().toString());
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "expense/save",
    cache : false,
    contentType : false,  
    processData : false,
    dataType: 'json',
    context: this,  
    data: $('#saveEmpForm').serialize(),
    success: function(data){ },
    error: function(jqXHR, status, error){ }
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes i have tried this, in cosole.log data entered in form shows up but not passed to controller, it gives 500 error for controller. once controller method is directly run in browser it shows NULL values passed to controller and model

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) for controller method i.e expense/save

Comment: I have found out there is some csrf protection but unable to correct it

Comment: Your expense/save method has some error. Try resolving it on backend.